# Why does this Javascript only run once per page?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have this Try-it-Yourself section to my website but for some reason when I am wanting to have more than one Try-it-Yourself section it will only work for the one at the top of the page. So if I had three of them on a page the top one would work in the way I want but the next two would do nothing.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="tryit">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Try It Yourself</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><textarea id="input" rows="10" cols="47"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input onclick="update();" type="button" value="Update"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><iframe id="output" name="output" width="600" height="300" ></iframe></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And the following Javascript:

```
function update()
{
   var tryitoutput = document.getElementById('input').value;
   window.frames['output'].document.documentElement.innerHTML = tryitoutput;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: ids have to be unique. If you add the exact same code you posted multiple times, you have more than one textarea with `id="input"`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks. How would I go around solving this then  without using different JS code every time to match the id's? I assumed you could change it to class="input" but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned, this is happening because there can't be more than one HTML element with same value of ID attribute. In your case javascript only finds the first element, that's why it doesn't work on later Update buttons. The simplest approach would be to set different ID attribute values for different "Try it yourself" boxes:

[Slightly modify your JS, see following jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/H9hRe/)

```
function update(tryItIndex) {
    var tryItOutput = document.getElementById('input-' + tryItIndex).value;
    window.frames['output-' + tryItIndex].document.documentElement.innerHTML = tryItOutput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are referring to the textarea and the output by id which means it will always just retrieve the first one. A quick fix would be having unique id's for these fields and send the names as parameters to the update function like update(inputId, outputId)